# Any tips or documentations for improving blender python skills?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, screencast

Recently, I set my goal to create my own `screencast key` for my python projects, but there's not much related instructions nor infos out there, like creating an empty box on the bottom right corner, button pressed events etc.. Nada. I thought this was easy such as a `HTML/CSS` thingys at the beginning and now I'm getting kicked my ass so hard.

I have been reading [API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#) but they don't describe what the built-in functions do in the end of results unlikely ***MOZILA documentation*** does. Feels like I'm getting lost my way.

As a person who have `Javascript/C#` experiences, where should I go to get the ball rolling?

Any recommendations?

Comment: What about learning from existing screencast keys? Search on GitHub, code is available

Comment: @chris I tried, but it's hard to figure out w/o basics. What I need is detailed documentations for getting used to the built-in functions step by step because at the end, I would know that which module is done here, and others done there. However, with that much have been pushed by google, I can't find the module instructions especially `blf` and `bgl`

Comment: If you have a blender cloud subscription [this tutorial](https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists) is available.  Much of it is available even if you don't; but afaict there aren't any written documents for blender python coding.  Certainly very little specific to those particular bits, which the Blender Cloud tutorial doesn't cover.